# Can I write ipython notebook(Jupyter) widgets in Ecmascript 6 or do they need to be transpiled?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The Ipython Notebooks now support javascript widgets. However, I was not sure if I could write a widget in Ecmascript 6 and make it work through the Ipython Notebook? I did not see any mention of version type in ipython widget repo on github. Just wanted to know what to expect when I did this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for Ecmascript 6 is planned for the Jupyter 6.0 major release. So until then, you can use a transpiler or perhaps Typescript to write widgets in the newer Ecmascript syntax.